# Heatmap dc.js - provide the color range manually

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, heatmap, dc.js

I'm not sure how to do this. I'm developing a heatmap dc.js. I want to set a range of colors manually. For example,

> var chart = dc.heatMap('#heatmapID');

```
chart
    .width(690)  //850
    .height(400)
    .margins({top: 10, right: 0, bottom: 50, left: 70})
    .dimension(dimension)
    .group(group)
    .keyAccessor(function(d) { return d.key[0]; })
    .valueAccessor(function(d) { return d.key[1]; })
    .colorAccessor(function(d) {return d.value.rate;});
chart.data(grouphelper.dataAccessor(dimension)); 
chart.colors(['#30d074', '#f3cb2c', '#ffa85c', '#ff604e']) 
    .calculateColorDomain();
```

The code above works but its automatically setting the colors base on the min and the max data (I'm assuming). For the chart.colors(....) i want to set a range manually but when I tried to apply a return function, for example,

```
 //Outside of the chart function
 var colors = ['#30d074', '#f3cb2c', '#ffa85c', '#ff604e'];
 function colorHeatMap() { 
  return d3.scale.threshold().domain([0.02,0.06,0.23]).range(colors);   }

 //now apply colorHeatMap function into the .color function.
 chart.colors(colorHeatMap()) .calculateColorDomain();
```

I received a _colors.domain is not a function error. When I remove the .calculateColorDomain(), the heatmap display all black boxes. My goal is to set the range manually for the 4 colors.  Please help. This approach works well with dc row charts but I cannot figure out how to do that for the heatmap.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot pass an array colors to the `chart.colors()` function; you must pass a d3 color scale object. That's why your heatmap shows all black boxes when you remove `calculateColorDomain()`.

I've run into a similar issue, and my solution was to create a `colorDomain` array and use it to access the colors. If you know which values you want to assign to each color, it's simple: just put the values in an array in that order.

```
var colorsDomain = [0.02, 0.06, 0.23];
var colors = ['#30d074', '#f3cb2c', '#ffa85c', '#ff604e'];

chart.colors(d3.scaleQuantize().domain([0, colors.length - 1]).range(colors))
       .colorAccessor(d => colorsDomain.indexOf(d.value.rate))
```

It looks like you might be using d3 v3 or lower, in which case you would want to use `d3.scale.quanitze()` instead of `d3.scaleQuantize()` in the colors function. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your response! I use your code. Though it sort of work but the color on the heatmap changes when the d.value.rate is equals to the colorsDomain values. I'm trying to make this for example, all d.value.rate below 0.02 will be green. And other d.value.rate values between 0.02 and 0.06 will be yellow and so on. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Ok. i made some changes using your code. I applied an if logic within the colorAccessor. For example, If(rate > 0.02) display this color. I think it works now. Thank you! The d3.scale.quantize() helps alot because I'm not sure how to write it inside the colors(). Thank you